# Ajax post to codeigniter controller giving 404, but making it to the controller?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, post

This is working perfect for me and my team locally, but once we pull it to the live server and try it, it gives me a 404 error but still provides the error response from the login function in the controller. I've been trying to figure this out for several hours now with no luck, and other posts haven't helped. I'm hoping it's something stupidly simple that I'm not seeing.

Edit: The most important part is that post data doesn't get sent on the server, but does locally.

Ajax call:

```
    var username = $('#loginUsername').val();
    var password = $('#loginPassword').val();

    var data = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login",
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            //response code
        }
    });
```

Controller function being called:

```
public function login() {
    $data = $_POST;

    if(!$data) {
        //error code
    } else {
        //success code
    }
}
```

And if it helps, here's the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a moron. Mod_rewrite wasn't enabled on the server. I thought it was because other functions were working as if they were, probably due to routing.

Comment: You can set error controller by routes.php that is present in application/config/routes.php

Answer (score 1):

If it running good on localhost that means may be your controller name you writing having case sensitive problem. So first check for case sensitive problem
than try it 
 `url: "<?php echo site_url('controllerName/functionName'); ?>"`

Comment: The cases for it are correct. The file name is lowercase, the class name has the first letter as upper case. I tried doing it this way, but it isn't working either.